# Downloading a signed PDF return corrputed file - Docusign API PHP

Tags: php, symfony, docusignapi

Trying to download the esigned PDF file from Docusign via PHP SDK. The API call returns success and the file is downloaded but it's corrupted and doesn't open or show anything.

Here's the code:

```
try {
            $envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
            $response = $envelopesApi->getDocument('ACCOUNT_ID', $documentId, $envelopeId);

            $fileContents = $response->getPathName();

            // Save the downloaded document to a file or process it as needed
            file_put_contents('path/filename.pdf', $fileContents);

            echo 'Signed document downloaded successfully.';
        } catch (ApiException $e) {
            echo 'Error while downloading the signed document: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        die;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok so to download the PDF correctly, replace:

```
$fileContents = $response->getPathName();
```

with

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents($response->getPathName());
```